# Amazon S3 cp keeps stopping partway through a copy procees

Tags: amazon-web-services, batch-file, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I have an overnight scheduled task (batch script) on a WS2K3 server which copies a ~2GB zip file to an S3 bucket for archival purposes.

I'm using AWS CLI v1 which I appreciate isn't ideal (nor is the fact the OS is out of date and unsupported).  I had enough problems coercing AWS CLI into actually running on the server!  (it's a legacy system the client refuses to update).

The copy process appears to have problems.  I suspect there are intermittent connectivity isses at the client's site and it's causing the copy process to exit.  I've added a debug argument to the command but for some reason the debug info isn't being echoed to the logfile so I can't identify the specific reason why it keeps exiting.  All I can do is retry until the copy completes.

The S3 upload section of the script is below

```
:s3cp
    aws configure set default.s3.max_concurrent_requests 1
    @echo S3 Backup Started: %date% %time%  
    aws s3 cp %backup%.zip %bucket% --debug
    IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 goto:s3cp
    @echo S3 Backup Finished: %date% %time% 
    goto exit
```

I've reduced concurrent connections in a attempt to restrict the resource overhead for this routine (the server struggles with most tasks!) but it's had no effect.

The last time it ran, the upload started at 20:04, restarted 23 times before finally completing a successful upload nearly 6 hours after the first copy process was called.

Are there any additional arguments I can pass to the AWS CLI to cope with timeouts and connection unreliability to ensure the process doesn't exit immediately?

Comment: Have you tried increasing the [retry](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-retries.html) values to some large value?  Also, you can add '2>&1` to the end of the aws call to redirect stderr to stdout and hopefully capture it in the log.

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't come across the retry value.  I've increased it and added the stderr redirection so hopefully will see it in this evening's log file.